# Need a PHP script to parse this XML with 'ID' as condition

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, parser-generator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Catalog SYSTEM "http://store.yahoo.com/doc/dtd/Catalog.dtd">
<Catalog StoreID="yhst-34564052343" StoreName="test.com" PublishTimestamp="1332786206">
<Item ID="10170090" TableID="yd-item">
<ItemField TableFieldID="more-image3" Value="test1"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="price-range" Value="23"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="more-image4" Value="test2"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="name" Value="Liquid Light Drop 1 Pendant Light"/>
</Item>
 <Item ID="10170191" TableID="yd-item">
<ItemField TableFieldID="more-image3" Value="test3"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="price-range" Value="34"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="more-image4" Value="test4"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="name" Value="Liquid Light Drop 4 Pendant Light"/>
</Item>
</Catalog>
```

I need output so that if ID 10170191 passed, then the output is as shown below:

```
more-image3:-test3
price-range:-34
more-image4:-test4
name:-Liquid Light Drop 4 Pendant Light
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and especially [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for some guidelines on how to ask questions here.

Comment: check the basics http://php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php

Comment: Or even more basic... http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Catalog SYSTEM "http://store.yahoo.com/doc/dtd/Catalog.dtd">
<Catalog StoreID="yhst-34564052343" StoreName="test.com" PublishTimestamp="1332786206">
<Item ID="10170090" TableID="yd-item">
<ItemField TableFieldID="more-image3" Value="test1"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="price-range" Value="23"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="more-image4" Value="test2"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="name" Value="Liquid Light Drop 1 Pendant Light"/>
</Item>
 <Item ID="10170191" TableID="yd-item">
<ItemField TableFieldID="more-image3" Value="test3"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="price-range" Value="34"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="more-image4" Value="test4"/>
<ItemField TableFieldID="name" Value="Liquid Light Drop 4 Pendant Light"/>
</Item>
</Catalog>';

$xml=simplexml_load_string( $xml );
$xpath=$xml->xpath( '//Catalog/Item[@ID="10170191"]' );
foreach( $xpath as $result ) {
    foreach( $result->ItemField as $path ) {
        echo $path['TableFieldID'] . ': ' . $path['Value'] . '<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much pushpesh...you must be a great PHP programmer